# Debugging - how to dump a dynamically allocated array from an optimized C program?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have a C program with a dynamically allocated array whose base pointer is a global variable.
An abbreviated example program is below:

```
double *array = NULL;

void foo() { /* complex calculations on array */ }
void bar() { /* complex calculations on array */ }

int main() {
  array = malloc( /* large size */ );
  foo();
  bar();
}
```

I must necessarily compile this with `gcc -O2 -no-pie program.c -lm`.
I can disassemble the program with `objdump -D -S a.out` to find the location of `array` and various specific instructions.
I want to write a script that does all of the following without my intervention:

1. Run the program in some sort of debug state and wait until a specific instruction is reached - I am assuming that the instruction would always be in a specific memory location because I used `-no-pie` at compilation.
2. Follow the global `array` pointer to the dynamically allocated memory - once again I am assuming that `-no-pie` will always ensure that the global pointer is at a specific memory location.
3. Dump a specific number of bytes from the dynamically allocated memory into a file.

I took a look at gdb, but most tutorials mention compiling with `-g -Og`, and I would prefer to avoid that in favor of raw memory locations for checkpoints and the location of `array`. Is this possible with gdb, or will I have to use another tool?

**Update:**

I will be using an architecture simulator to intentionally inject bitflips into the program at various points. I want to determine how the bitflips corrupt the program data, specifically array. I want to know the value of array at various points in the program to see how the effect of the bitflip propagates.

I cannot add extra print functions in the middle of the program in the source code, because the program that I am testing must be comparable to a program that does the entire computation at once without any prints in between.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info seems relevant here. What _actual_ problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Given a program that I must compile with `-O2 -no-pie -lm` for compatibility with another tool, I want to be able to dump the contents of `array` at any point in the program doing a complex series of computations on `array`.

Comment: "I want ..." -- yes, you already said that. What is the _goal_ of that exercise?

Comment: I will be using an architecture simulator to intentionally inject bitflips into the program at various points. I want to determine how the bitflips corrupt the program data, specifically `array`. I want to know the value of `array` at various points in the program to see how the effect of the bitflip propagates. I cannot add extra print functions in the middle of the program in the source code, because the program that I am testing must be comparable to a program that does the entire computation at once without any prints in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible with gdb

Yes, GDB is perfectly capable of doing this.

Let's start by making an *actual* working example:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int SZ = 20;
double *array = NULL;

void foo()
{
  for (int j = 0; j < SZ; j++)
    array[j] = 2.0;
}

void bar()
{
  for (int j = 0; j < SZ; j++)
    array[j] /= 3.0;
}


int main()
{
  array = malloc(sizeof(double) * SZ);
  foo();
  __asm__("nop");  // For a breakpoint
  bar();
  __asm__("nop");  // For a breakpoint

  return 0;
}
```

Compile this with `gcc -O2 -fno-inline -no-pie t.c` (using `-fno-inline` because otherwise `foo()` gets inlined).

```
gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401040 <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000401044 <+4>:     mov    $0xa0,%edi
   0x0000000000401049 <+9>:     callq  0x401030 <malloc@plt>
   0x000000000040104e <+14>:    mov    %rax,0x2fcb(%rip)        # 0x404020 <array>
   0x0000000000401055 <+21>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000401057 <+23>:    callq  0x401160 <foo>
   0x000000000040105c <+28>:    nop
   0x000000000040105d <+29>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000040105f <+31>:    callq  0x401190 <bar>
   0x0000000000401064 <+36>:    nop
   0x0000000000401065 <+37>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000401067 <+39>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x000000000040106b <+43>:    retq
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) b *0x000000000040105c
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40105c
(gdb) b *0x0000000000401064
Breakpoint 2 at 0x401064

(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040105c in main ()

(gdb) p &array
$1 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x404020 <array>

(gdb) p (*(double**)0x404020)[0]@20
$2 = {2 <repeats 20 times>}

(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000401064 in main ()
(gdb) p (*(double**)0x404020)[0]@20
$3 = {0.66666666666666663 <repeats 20 times>}
```

As you can see, we've observed all the values we want.

You can hard-code the addresses of the two breakpoints, and the address of the `array` into your script (here `gdb.script`):

```
break *0x40105c
break *0x401064
run
print (*(double**)0x404020)[0]@20
cont
print (*(double**)0x404020)[0]@20
cont
```

And run gdb as `gdb -batch -x gdb.script ./a.out`, which produces:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40105c
Breakpoint 2 at 0x401064
Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040105c in main ()
$1 = {2 <repeats 20 times>}

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000401064 in main ()
$2 = {0.66666666666666663 <repeats 20 times>}
[Inferior 1 (process 1838617) exited normally]
```

The only remaining part is the "dump bytes into a file", which can be achieved with the `dump memory` GDB command:

```
(gdb) help dump memory
Write contents of memory to a raw binary file.
Arguments are FILE START STOP.  Writes the contents of memory within the
range [START .. STOP) to the specified FILE in raw target ordered bytes.
```

P.S. You could also get rid of the `Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040105c in main ()` output by setting the breakpoints to `silent` mode, like so:

```
break *0x40105c
commands
  silent
  print (*(double**)0x404020)[0]@20
  cont
end

break *0x401064
commands
  silent
  print (*(double**)0x404020)[0]@20
  cont
end

run
```

The output becomes:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40105c
Breakpoint 2 at 0x401064
$1 = {2 <repeats 20 times>}
$2 = {0.66666666666666663 <repeats 20 times>}
[Inferior 1 (process 1839098) exited normally]
```

Comment: This sounds quite promising. I shall test this out.